# Convert the following jQuery code to pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert the following commented lines to pure JS?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add").click(function() {
        var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last");
    var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
    fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
    var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" />");
    var fType = $("<select class=\"fieldtype\"><option value=\"checkbox\">Checked</option><option value=\"textbox\">Text</option><option value=\"textarea\">Paragraph</option></select>");
    var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
    removeButton.click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append(fType);
    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
});
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/87e1fhva/)

Comment: I see zero comments. Also, your [mcve] must exist here and not on a third party site

Comment: Which specific part(s) is(are) causing problems?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your issue?

Comment: I could probably manually convert this to JS in a couple of minutes. You should do the same, and if you dont know, now is a good time to learn.

Comment: @KevinHernandez I just learned JS and I barley write a code xD, Could you please help me